# RGBDSLAM fails rosmake and rosdep in fuerte

Tags: slam, navigation, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use rgbdslam in fuerte on 12.04 LTS. I was able to overcome some problems, like the dependency on eigen by following [these directions](http://answers.ros.org/question/38989/rgbdslam-with-ros-fuerte-installed/).

Now I am having a different error.

```
bowser@bowser-ros:~/fuerte_workspace$ rosdep install rgbdslam
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rgbdslam: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [gl2ps]
```

I tried to install the packages as described in the link, but they were already up to date. Rosmake also fails with following error:

```
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLEW
      /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lIL
      collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
      make[1]: *** [siftgpu] Error 1
      make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bowser/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam/external/siftgpu/linux'
      
      ------------------------------------------------------------------
      
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:103 (MESSAGE):
        SiftGPU cannot be compiled.  Returned: 2

  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

the full build_output.log is [here](http://pastebin.com/M0xrrVCS).

I am trying to learn more about SiftGPU to figure out what problem could be, but I'm not really sure where to look right now, or if siftgpu itself is the problem, or if I'm missing some other dependency.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39806/rgbdslam-fails-rosmake-and-rosdep-in-fuerte/) by [jerdman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2816/jerdman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like you lack a dependency of SiftGPU. Either search on http://packages.ubuntu.com/ for a package containing libGLEW and libIL or disable it at the top of CMakeLists.txt.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-26**:
Is this a bug in `rgbdslam`? The bugs link on the stack page is broken: http://ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam_freiburg

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-07-30**:
rgbdslam doesn't support fuerte yet (and will not until at least september), so I don't consider this a bug I can fix yet. I don't know what is wrong with that page, do you? It definitely is indexed, since ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam comes from a subdirectory. Maybe a problem with the stack.xml?